# Forward a call to a conference call number with hashtag and extension using Twilio

Tags: twilio, phone-call

I have set up a phone number on Twilio that is forwarding a call successfully. Now I want to set up something like Webex as the target number where it's necessary to send extension digits and hashtags (in order to choose the right conference ID, in this example with Webex).

I couldn't get this set up in Twilio, all attempts via Studio Flow or with custom Functions didn't work out.

I guess my actual question at this time would be: is that even possible? Can voice calls be forwarded in that way? By now I doubt it but I'm struggling to google my way to a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can send digits to the call using the [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) element within a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial).

`<Number>` has the [`sendDigits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits) which you can use to send DTMF tones to the call. You can add `w` for a 0.5s delay and then the numbers. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number sendDigits="wwww1928">
            415-123-4567
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

will wait 2 seconds (4 * 0.5s) and then dial `1928`.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Awesome, this did exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why I had so much problems doing this, it looks so simple, now that I know how it works :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to have helped.